# How can I make part of a Perl regular expression optional?

Tags: regex, perl

I want match

```
 my @array = ( 'Tree' , 'JoeTree');

    foreach (@array ) {
      if ( $_ =~ /^(Joe)Tree/gi) {
        print "matched $_";
      }
    }
```

It matching only JoeTree. It's not matching Tree ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
if (/^(?:Joe)?Tree/gi)
```

- We've made the `Joe` part optional.
- Also you can change `(..)` to
  `(?:...)` as you are just grouping.
- Also `$_ =~` part is redundant as by
  default we check in `$_`

Answer (score 5):

You missed a `?`: `/^(Joe)?Tree/gi`